# Paired t-test in R

Tags: r, for-loop, hypothesis-test

I am trying to run a paired t-test in R on data grouped by factors:

```
> head(i.o.diff,n=20)
#   Difference Tree.ID Tree.Name   Ins Outs
#1        0.20    AK-1      Akun  1.20  1.0
#2       -1.60    AK-2      Akun  0.40  2.0
#3       -0.60    AK-3      Akun  1.40  2.0
#4        0.40    AK-4      Akun  0.40  0.0
#5        1.30    AK-5      Akun  1.80  0.5
#6        2.70     J-1     Jaror 10.20  7.5
#7        6.60     J-2     Jaror 10.60  4.0
#8        2.50     J-3     Jaror  6.00  3.5
#9        7.50     J-4     Jaror 22.00 14.5
#10      -4.50     J-5     Jaror  5.00  9.5
#11       3.50    Ce-1     Ku'ch  4.00  0.5
#12      -0.70    Ce-2     Ku'ch  4.80  5.5
#13       1.60    Ce-3     Ku'ch  2.60  1.0
#14      -2.40    Ce-4     Ku'ch  2.60  5.0
#15      -1.75    Ce-5     Ku'ch  2.25  4.0
```

I first tried using:

```
pairwise.t.test(i.o.diff$In,i.o.diff$Out,g=i.o.diff$Tree.Name,paired=TRUE,pool=FALSE,p.adj="none",alternative=c("less"),mu=0)
```

but I get the error

> Error in complete.cases(x, y) : not all arguments have the same length

which doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me.

I considered using `ddply()`, `apply()`, and `summaryBy()`, but couldn't get it to work because the inputs for the paired t-test require 2 vectors and most of the previous functions I mention seem to work best when only one column is being "operated" upon.

In order to get around this, I tried to use a for loop to achieve the same end:

```
for(i in unique(i.o.diff$Tree.Name)) {
  pair_sub<-subset(i.o.diff,Tree.Name==i) 
  t.pair<-t.test(pair_sub$Ins,pair_sub$Outs,paired="True")
  print(t.pair)
}
```

However when I do this, I get error

> in paired || !is.null(y) : invalid 'x' type in x||y

So I checked `typeof(pair_sub$Ins)`. Turns out that type is double, which is numeric, so I am not sure why the paired t-test is not working.  Any ideas as to how to fix either of these methods?

Comment: i.o.diff$In shoud be i.o.diff$Ins, with an 's' at the end... same for i.o.diff$Outs. No?

Comment: Simple typos are a reason to close if the questioner does not delete.

Comment: I tried reproducing this; even after correcting for typos, I don't get the same errors you get. You might want to restart your R session afresh and try again.

Comment: That is correct Roger, but I just fixed the typos and got the exact same errors.  I did restart my R session to no avail...

Comment: Furthermore, there were no typos in my for loop, so that doesn't answer that issue.

Comment: I also checked

`> length(i.o.diff$Ins)`
`[1] 51`
`> length(i.o.diff$Outs)`
`[1] 51`

So I still can't figure why I get that error for pairwise.t.test.

Answer (score 0):

Removed the quotes around TRUE in the for loop.  Works great now.

Answer (score 0):

From R documentation:
t.test {stats} R Documentation Student’s t-Test:

```
Description:

     Performs one and two sample t-tests on vectors of data. Usage t.test(x, …)

Default S3 method:
t.test(x, y = NULL, alternative = c(“two.sided”, “less”, “greater”), mu = 0, paired = FALSE, var.equal = FALSE, conf.level = 0.95, …)
```